# How do I write equations with sin in .NET Math class?

Tags: .net, math

I know how to solve this using a calculator, but how do I solve it using the Math class in .NET?

```
(15/sin(v))=(10/sin(37))
```

Comment: There are no functions in .NET for solving equations. They are for _evaluating_ equations.

Comment: Are you looking for a reference like this? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Important point: most math code works in radians; "37" looks like degrees. Make sure you are using the correct unit.

Comment: Re unfamiliar English terminology, I would search for "symbolic equation solver" or "symbolic math" which might lead you to things like http://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/NewtonEquationSolver.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math` doesn't offer a *solver*; it simply provides a few tools for common math operations. You would have to *solve* it manually, or fine a solver lib.

But anecdotally:

```
var v = 180 * Math.Asin(15 * Math.Sin(37 * Math.PI / 180) / 10) / Math.PI;
  // ~= 64.518 degrees
```

assuming you want your units in degrees.

Comment: I think 15 should be in the numerator and 10 in the denominator, Marc.  Check me.

Comment: @duffymo yeah, sorry; wasn't focusing

Comment: Put it back - the rest was correct.  It often happens with haste.

Comment: @duffymo I'm reluctant to, especially since the OP's angle unit is ambiguous; 37 radians sounds unlikely (edit: ah, I see you had the same thought)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's totally wrong.  Trig functions in Java, C, C++, C#, JavaScript and FORTRAN all take radians.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly, this is nothing more than simple algebra.

```
15/sin(v) = 10/sin(37);
```

I'll assume that 37 means "degrees".  You'll want *radians*.

Multiply both sides by sin(37)*sin(v)/10:

```
15*sin(37)/10 = sin(v)
```

Solve for v:

```
v = inverse sin(1.5*sin(37))
```

Personally, I find the lack of mathematical knowledge on SO appalling.  It's often not even high level math.  People have issues with simple high school algebra.  Forget about calculus!  How can you be a competent programmer without such a fundamental skill?

Comment: Re "Personally, I find ...", some of us just prefer to [avoid trig operators based on inf series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry) for non-symbolic computational geometry because the available performant numeric primitives are limited-precision and/or have non-uniform density of representable values.

Comment: I have no idea what this comment is all about.

Comment: +1 You could have pointed out the Asin function though, but apparently the OP didn't like your personal notion.

Comment: Don't care what you or the OP think about my personal notion.

Comment: I'll point to to phant0m and the OP that I explicitly wrote "inverse sin" in my solution.  And my recollection is fuzzy, but I think I was the first to say that a numerical algorithm wasn't needed, just algebra.

Comment: I don't disagree with your opinion, I just noticed that you received the -1 immediately before the other answer got accepted.